# Select variable string value

Tags: javascript

I would like to take input from a text box, concatenate its value with a string, then copy it to the clipboard.

I get stuck at `.select()`, because it doesn't work with the variable. I inserted the `alert` before `.select()` to check its value, but that's okay. The alerted value should be copied to the clipboard.

```js
function copyLink() {
  var siteNumber = document.getElementById("number");
  var home = "http://www.website.com/site";
  var link = home.concat(siteNumber.value);
  alert(link);
  link.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + link);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number">
<button onclick="copyLink()">Copy input as link</button>
```

Comment: What this line `link.select();` suppose to do

Comment: [HTMLInputElement#select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) is only defined on HTMLInputElements. You can't call `select` on a string. You can put the string in an element and then select it using something like this: https://techoverflow.net/2018/03/30/copying-strings-to-the-clipboard-using-pure-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text to copy has to be in an element in the DOM, which is what you call `select` on (not a string). See comments:

```js
function copyLink() {
  // Get the value
  var siteNumber = document.getElementById("number").value;
  // Build the link
  var link = "http://www.website.com/site" + siteNumber;
  // Create an input to put it in and append it to the DOM
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.value = link;
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  // Select and copy
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  // Remove the temporary input
  document.body.removeChild(input);
  alert("Copied the text: " + link);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number">
<button onclick="copyLink()">Copy input as link</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to append the value to the dom to `select`. For that case create a `hidden` input and add set its value to link. Then once copied again set it to empty string.

For string concatenation you can use `+`

```js
function copyLink() {
  var siteNumber = document.getElementById("number");
  var home = "http://www.website.com/site";
  var link = home + siteNumber.value;
  let _h = document.getElementById('hiddenIp');
  _h.value = link
  //alert(link);
  _h.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  _h.value = '';
  alert("Copied the text: " + link);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number">

<button onclick="copyLink()">Copy input as link</button>

<input type='hidden' id='hiddenIp'>
```

Answer (score 0):

`select()` only works with elements. You need to create one.

Or you can save value temporarily in the input element.

```js
function copyLink() {
  var siteNumber = document.getElementById("number");
  var home = "http://www.website.com/site";
  var temp = siteNumber.value  

  siteNumber.value = home + temp
  siteNumber.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + siteNumber.value);

  siteNumber.value = temp
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number">
<button onclick="copyLink()">Copy input as link</button>
```